# How to center a form in the middle of the page

Tags: html, css

I have a simple form and I just need it centered in the middle of the page. Like, directly square in the middle. But no matter what I change in my CSS file it stays on the left side of the page.

My HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Search</title>
    </head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="search.css" type="text/css">
    <body>

        <div>
            <form action="https://google.com/search">
                <input id="search" type="text" name="q">
                <br>
                <input id="button" type="submit" value="Google Search">
            </form>
        </div>

       
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: For example `form { width: 250px; margin: 0 auto; }` will give the form a width and center it horizontaly in the middle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of flexbox's [`align-items`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-items) property:

```css
body{
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
  height:100vh;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Search</title>
    </head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="search.css" type="text/css">
    <body>

        <div>
            <form action="https://google.com/search">
                <input id="search" type="text" name="q">
                <br>
                <input id="button" type="submit" value="Google Search">
            </form>
        </div>

       
    </body>
</html>
```